# Choose NoSQL database type

Tags: nosql

I have an app and a list of all the actions a user has done while using it.

To put an example, for each user I have data like this:

- "start"
- "country":"aa"
- "session":"0"
- "menu":"main"
- "menu":"play"
- "play_level":"1"
- "play_during":"70 seconds"
- "purchase":"metal hammer"
- "play_level":"2"

I have to choose a database where I could enter this kind of data, and they, in example, query "all the players that bought the metal hammer before level 2".

This is obviously not a SQL scenario and I have zero experience in NoSQL. I've been examining types of NoSQL databases (column, document, key-value, graph, ...) and I suppose that a key-value DB type is the one I should be using, but I'm not able to find if I can have duplicate keys, and if I can query for entries to appear before other entries (purchase xyz **before** play_level 2)

Are key-value NoSQL databases able to handle this kind of data and query or should I choose another NoSQL database type?

Comment: "*This is obviously not a SQL scenario*" Why not? Looks like a pretty good SQL scenario to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can solve this by SQL as @Vincent said, e.g. by having a table with the following fields:

- userId: whatever
- timestamp: Date
- eventName: string
- params: string or number, maybe multiple fields. NoSQL becomes relevant at this point.

Here's some dummy example to start with, you should refine it though.

```
SELECT u, e1, e2
FROM users u, events e1, events e2
WHERE e1.userId = u.userId
AND e1.eventName = 'play_level'
AND e1.paramsNumber = 2
AND e2.userId = u.userId
AND e2.eventName = 'purchase'
AND e2.params = 'metal hammer'
AND e2.timestamp < e1.timestamp
```

Maybe better if using `LEFT JOIN`, some `GROUP BY` would be necessay to prevent duplications (e.g. she played level 2 twice). Appropriate indexing (`userId`, `eventName`) can get better performance.

BTW I'm using MongoDB in many projects, you can give it a try, it's not that difficult. But note that NoSQL could be *your decision*, not a functional requirement.

Comment: Thanks Gábor & Vincent. I didn't thought of structuring the data this way around a timestamp. (honestly I'm not used to databases and except for some SELECTs, most of my knowledge is theoretical from the uni like a thousand years ago :) ) I'll take some time to implementate the solution and will come back to confirm it or update the question. Thanks!